# loop to find value matching condition produces type mismatch

Tags: vba, loops, type-mismatch

I'm trying to loop through a range looking if the value matches another value from different range, if it does it will input the value that matched. The loop worked once, inserted the matched value into "E3" and then produced "type mismatch" error. Is there a kind person who could advise why my code doesn't work? I'd appreciate that so much...

```
Sub find_that()
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Activate 
    For Each a In Worksheets("Output").Range("E3:E28")
        For Each b In Worksheets("SelectionOfSKU").Range("F3:F66")
            If a.Offset(0, -3).Value = b.Value And b.Offset(0, 2) <> 0 Then
                a.Value = b.Offset(0, -4).Value 'If condition met, input the matched value
            End If
        Next b
    Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: Please indicate in your question which line actually caused the error. Once you've done that, it will be easier to isolate the exact expression which is causing the error.

Comment: I'd say `b.Offset(0, 2).VALUE <> 0` is the only thing I really see, but the default option when not declared should be `.Value` so without more on which line is erroring...

Comment: This is going to be tricky to diagnose because we also don't know if your error occurred while still in the b loop under `a = E3` or during the second b loop with `a = E4`...

Comment: It occurs during the first loop, while still in E3....

Answer (score 0):

the puzle is solved, code is below:

```
Sub find_sku2()

Dim a As Long, i As Long
Dim b As Long, j As Long

i = Sheets("Output").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
j = Sheets("SelectionOfSKU").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For a = 3 To i
    For b = 1 To j
            If Sheets("Output").Cells(a, 2).Value = Sheets("SelectionOfSKU").Cells(b, 6).Value And Sheets("SelectionOfSKU").Cells(b, 8).Value <> 0 Then
                Sheets("Output").Cells(a, 5).Value = Sheets("SelectionOfSKU").Cells(b, 2).Value
            End If
        Next
Next
```

End Sub